# How to Rotate Map View from the user current position in android

Tags: android, android-mapview

I am pointing the user current location always bottom center in android map view.So the user will able to see only the north side map and he is not able to see south side app.if the user turns towards south the user should see the south side map.

I am getting bearing angle of the user using Sensor manager.if i rotate the map the current position of

the user changes from bottom center to some where how can i handle this.

Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using `mapView.setRotation(float bearing)`. That's what I use (I have an app similar to yours). I'm not sure what API level that was introduced in, but it works for me (2.3.4). Make sure you call `mapView.invalidate()` after you've rotated the map.

Comment: I used that rotate but while rotating some part of the map on screen coming black but it should be fill with map whole the screen

Comment: @Ajay did u find any solution for this,I am also trying to do the same thing but I couldn't find any,can u please help me if you find any solution for this..Thanks....